# Apt application does not work

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04

I have installed a package:

`sudo apt install mueller7-dict`

and it has installed successfully, but neither the application has appeared in my start menu, nor it opens when I type

`mueller7-dict` to terminal. How to open the application?

Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to be an application that can run? I think you need a stand-alone dict client to view dict files.

Comment: @ArturMeinild no, I am not sure, I just assumed that any apt package can be ran (especally since it is a dictionary). What do I need to do in order to run the app?

Comment: As mentioned, I think you need some kind of dict client - I suppose the dict files are only dictionary files that need some other program to be viewed.

Comment: @shiu'sho see updated answer below. GoldenDict can use such dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [its filelist](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/mueller7-dict/filelist) there are no executables in the package.

The dictionary database may be used by some other applications. For example install GoldenDict with

```
sudo apt-get install goldendict
```

and then add dictionary to it:

1. go to *Edit* → *Dictionaries*
2. on the *Sources*, *Files* click *Add* button
3. add the `/usr/share/opendict/dictionaries/plain/mueller7.dict.dz` (or `/usr/share/dictd` which is more universal) folder recursively
4. click *Rescan now*
5. click *OK*
6. enter some word into search field and enjoy

   [image: GoldenDict with mueller7 dictionary]

Comment: Thanks! it indeed worked! But the dictionary itself is poor, are there any recommendations for russian - english dictionary for Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but `dict-freedict-eng-rus` may be better. Also you can find some third-party site with [GoldenDict](http://goldendict.org/dictionaries.php)-related dictionaries.

Comment: just installed `dict-freedict-eng-rus` and having the same problem - I cannot start the application

Comment: It is a dictionary for GoldenDict. You have to it with the same way.

Comment: okay. I think both of those dictionaries are english to russian and I am looking the opposite, so it would be russian to english. Any recommendations?

Comment: As I have wrote above, you have to find some third-party [dictionary](http://goldendict.org/dictionaries.php) in the format supported by GoldenDict. It may be ABBYY Lingvo .dsl or other files. I do not have exact recommendation and link.